# Url exposes the application directory

Tags: wcf, url

In my WCF service application , images are saved into application directory. So in one of the service call, it returns the image(http request to the url- `http://mydomain:88/Images/Tree/test.png`) to the client application.( a mobile application). The url exposes the application directory, so is this a good practice? All the call to the service is protected using basic authentication. But still is this good practice to exposing the directory structure in url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've done is expose a little information to the world about your directory structure behind the scenes - probably not a "best practice". But generally, I'd say you're safe if:

1. you don't expose the directories to browsing (like via an IIS
   setting)
2. the web service or proxy is located behind a firewall    within a
   DMZ
3. the WCF requests are authenticated/authorized before
   content is delivered.

You can fix this without too much work, though. Assuming the "Test.png" is the file the client is trying to download, change the host-side endpoint so that it's just ".../Images/Tree/Connect" that receives the file name as a parameter in the Get(). The host and clients would have to change, but it's not a big change.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with the project.